# Running Sample Application on jBPM

Tags: jboss, jbpm

After struggling I am able to run jBPM. Now I trying to run a sample application but am unable to succeed. I followed this URL but not succeeded.

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_process_automation_manager/7.0/html-single/creating_and_running_a_red_hat_business_optimizer_solver_for_employee_rostering_using_business_central/index

If anyone has tried and got success, please guide me on how to run a sample application of jBPM.

Please don't **downgrade** my question. I am a novice in jBPM why I am asking these questions in this community

Thanks in Advance.